# POM Parent: Maven failed to execute mojo

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am currently working on a Java project using Maven.
Eclipse signals a problem on the `<parent>` section of the `pom.xml` file.
I am not yet trying to build the project (though I reckon that Maven/eclipse kind of constantly checks for compile-time errors), but this problem renders impossible importing from the dependencies.

Here's the error I get:

```
Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce {execution: enforce-rules} (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce:enforce-rules:validate)

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce {execution: enforce-rules}
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeMojo(MavenExecutionContext.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.lambda$0(MavenExecutionContext.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.lambda$1(MavenBuilderImpl.java:139)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution enforce-rules of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce failed: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "object" is null
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeMojo(MavenExecutionContext.java:338)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "object" is null
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven31DependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(Maven31DependencyGraphBuilder.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.DefaultDependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(DefaultDependencyGraphBuilder.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.DefaultDependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(DefaultDependencyGraphBuilder.java:66)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanCircularDependencies.getDependenciesToCheck(BanCircularDependencies.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanCircularDependencies.execute(BanCircularDependencies.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 33 more
```

My pom.xml is most basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 

    <parent>  <!-- This line gets the error -->
        <groupId>org.scijava</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-scijava</artifactId>
        <version>31.1.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scijava.public</id>
            <url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- imglib2 and scifio-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've tried "cleaning" the project, updating eclipse, with and without forced snapshots, adding the maven War plugin to the `pom.xml`, closing/reopening, but none seemed to help.

EDIT: Also have to mention that I tried with [this](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2-tutorials/blob/master/pom.xml) pom.xml (from the imglib2 tutorials), which uses the same dependencies as me, and still had the same error.
I don't think that this error has been there all along, but it now appears on all my projects. I can't remember when it first popped up... I think it might have occurred when I created my second project (this one) using a pom.xml.

I am quite close to completely clueless as to what is happening here so any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though `<parent>` still displays the same error, I think I partly solved the problem by adding the dependencies that are necessary for the MyMojo.java code to run.
The MyMojo.java code complained that it could not resolved the `import org.apache.maven` so I added these lines to the pom.xml's dependecies:

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The problem still persists though as it is now the MyMojoTest.java code that complains about not being able to import `org.apache.maven.plugin.testing`, even when the [plugin testing](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/dependency-info.html) dependency is added to the main pom.xml.